# Method references to raw types harmful?

Tags: java-8, javac, method-reference, raw-types, ecj

The code below contains a reference to `Enum::name` (notice no type parameter).

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> ColumnType<T, String> enumColumn(Class<T> klazz) {
    return simpleColumn((row, label) -> valueOf(klazz, row.getString(label)), Enum::name);
}

public static <T, R> ColumnType<T, R> simpleColumn(BiFunction<JsonObject, String, T> readFromJson,
        Function<T, R> writeToDb) {
 // ...
}
```

Javac reports a warning during compilation:

> [WARNING]  found raw type: java.lang.Enum missing type arguments for
>   generic class java.lang.Enum

Changing the expression to `Enum<T>::name` causes the warning to go away.

However Idea flags the `Enum<T>::name` version with a warning that:

> Explicit type arguments can be inferred

In turn Eclipse (ECJ) doesn't report any problems with either formulation.

**Which of the three approaches is correct?**

On one hand raw types are rather nasty. If you try to put some other type argument e.g.  `Enum<Clause>::name` will cause the compilation to fails so it's some extra protection.

On the other hand the above reference is equivalent to `e -> e.name()` lambda, and this formulation doesn't require type arguments.

Enviorment:

- Java 8u91
- IDEA 15.0.3 Community
- ECJ 4.5.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “raw method reference”. Whilst raw types exist to help the migration of pre-Generics code, there can’t be any pre-Generics usage of method references, hence there is no “compatibility mode” and type inference is the norm. The [Java Language Specification §15.13. Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) states:

> If a method or constructor is generic, the appropriate type arguments may either be inferred or provided explicitly. Similarly, the type arguments of a generic type mentioned by the method reference expression may be provided explicitly or inferred.
>
> Method reference expressions are always poly expressions

So while you may call the type before the `::` a “raw type” when it referes to a generic class without specifying type arguments, the compiler will still infer the generic type signature according to the target function type. That’s why producing a warning about “raw type usage” makes no sense here.

Note that, e.g.

```
BiFunction<List<String>,Integer,String> f1 = List::get;
Function<Enum<Thread.State>,String> f2 = Enum::name;
```

can be compiled with `javac` without any warning (the specification names similar examples where the type should get inferred), whereas

```
Function<Thread.State,String> f3 = Enum::name;
```

generates a warning. The [specification says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1-200-C.1-A.2) about this case:

> In the second search, if `P1`, ..., `Pn` is not empty and `P1` is a subtype of *ReferenceType*, then the method reference expression is treated as if it were a method invocation expression with argument expressions of types `P2`, ..., `Pn`. If *ReferenceType* is a raw type, and there exists a parameterization of this type, `G<...>`, that is a supertype of `P1`, the type to search is the result of capture conversion (§5.1.10) applied to `G<...>`;…

So in the above example, the compiler should infer `Enum<Thread.State>` as the parametrization of `Enum` that is a supertype of `Thread.State` to search for an appropriate method and come to the same result as for the `f2` example. It somehow *does* work, though it generates the nonsensical raw type warning.

---

Since apparently, `javac` only generates this warning when it has to search for an appropriate supertype, there is a simple solution for your case. Just use the exact type to search:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> ColumnType<T, String> enumColumn(Class<T> klazz) {
    return simpleColumn((row, label) -> valueOf(klazz, row.getString(label)), T::name);
}
```

This compiles without any warning.

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive response. 
Just to be clear: there is no possibility to do "unsafe" operations by means of a raw *ReferenceType*? (Something like assigning a `List<String>` to a `List<Long>` variable via a `List` cast)

Comment: That would require raw types within the functional signature of the *target type*, but then, of course, an appropriate warning should be generated *there*. For example, consider `BiConsumer<List,Object> add=List::add;` which expresses an unchecked operation, but it’s the declaration of the `BiConsumer` that is responsible, not the method reference.

Comment: Is this something that it makes sense for the compiler to call out, or should this be considered/filed as a bug?

Comment: @M.Justin if you still get this with an up-to-date compiler, it should be filed as bug. But I think, all recent compilers agree on not issuing a warning.

Comment: @Holger Thanks.  I encountered this error in Java 17, so it's still present.  It's possible I hit a similar but different scenario; I'll test it out more when I get the opportunity.