# Java Typed Generics in Collectors

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to stream and java and I would to know what is the difference between `ArrayList::new` and `ArrayList<Node>::new` in my collectors method`.stream().collect(ArrayList???::new, (acc, x) -> acc.add(x), ..)`

Comment: The same as `new ArrayList<>()` vs `new ArrayList<Node>()`.

Comment: @shmosel Did you mean `new ArrayList()`?

Comment: @Andreas No, that would be a raw type.

Comment: @shmosel Ah yes, [right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37189738/5221149). Guess I should've known that. DOH!

Comment: I get it now what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen `ArrayList<String>::new` used anywhere. The javadoc of Collectors has several examples, and all use `HashSet::new`, or `TreeMap::new`, for example.

As far as I know, you would only need to specify the generic type when the type inference is not able to figure out the right generic type, but I can't remember seeing that happen.

Comment: u cant always use HashSet::new or TreeMap::new, i guess you use the type info then

Comment: The source code for [`Collectors.toCollection()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.toCollection%28java.util.function.Supplier%29) uses an explicit type on a method call, though it doesn't seem necessary there. I've used it once to work around an Eclipse inference bug. I've also needed `obj::<T>method` before.

Answer (score -3):

They are both just different ways that you can make arrays in Java.

```
new ArrayList<Node>()
```

The array style above is a generic array type. This means your specifiying what type of array list it is. So in the example above whatver is in the <> simply defines what kind of array it is e.g. String, or it could even be another class.