# How can I suppress rawType of method reference?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I have a method looks like this.

```java
public <E extends Enum<E> & Some> void setOther(final E some) {
    setOther(ofNullable(some).map(e -> e.name()).orElse(null);
}
```

Now IntelliJ suggests to use a method reference for `e -> e.name()` part.

And I changed it.

```java
public <E extends Enum<E> & Some> void setOther(final E some) {
    setOther(ofNullable(some).map(Enum::name).orElse(null);
}
```

Now compiler complains about it.

```
... ....java:nnn: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Enum
        setOther(ofNullable(some).map(Enum::name).orElse(null));
                                      ^
```

Putting `@SuppressWarnings({"uncheked"})` doesn't work.

How can I eliminate it? Should I stick to `e -> e.name()`?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? And please include the exact warning. Maybe it doesn't even come from the compiler but from another source code checking tool that you have installed. Javac of 1.8.0_131 nor the Java compiler of Eclipse 4.7.2RC2 generate any warnings for your code. (They do initially show errors because you are missing a closing parenthesis `)` in your first two code snippets.)

Comment: Should it be `Some::name` then?

Comment: And in any case, if the warning is for `[rawtypes]` you should use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`

Comment: `Optional` is not a general replacement for if/else.  You can write this method as `setOther(some != null ? some.name() : null);`, which is a lot more readable in my opinion.  And it will eliminate generics issues entirely.

Comment: @user7 `Some` is an interface.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I got this warning with Gradle 4.4.1 and JDK 1.8.0_161.

Comment: While it’s possible to work-around it using `E::name`, I consider the warning a compiler bug. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37189738/2711488).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.map(Enum::name)
```

To

```
.map(E::name)
```

Comment: Oh God. I've never known this!